# Latex rendering pdf incorrectly

Tags: xetex

so i think latex is using second page. it's just 2 and i can't remove it. can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\setmainfont{Segoe UI}
\usepackage[georgian]{babel}

\title{sipი}
\author{dd\\kk\\bb}
\date{9 მაისი, 2023}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter*{\centering{სარჩევი}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I'm not quite understanding your question.  If you just use latin letters and take out the font commands, does the problem persist?  `\chapter` starts a new page, so the chapter title should be at the top of the second page.  Is that what you're trying to change?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean? Try `article` instead class `book` is my wild guess ...

Comment: @Teepeemm my problem still persists, and yes chapter title should be at the top of the second and not third page

Comment: @Mensch it gives me bunch of errors